# Statements with rare counter-examples

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

This is a soft question. I'm searching for examples of mathmatical statements (preferably in number theory, but other topics are also fine), that seem to be true, but are actually not. Statements where observing some examples would let you think it is always true, but then there is a well hidden counter-example.

If Riemann's $\zeta$ function had a zero beside the critical line, this would be such an example I'm looking for. Or if Fermat's Last Theorem would be false.

Do you know any such surprising counter-exmaples?

Comment: See the prime generating polynomials: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: The number of primes $\le x$ of the form $4k+3$ is never greater than the number of primes $\le x$ of the form $4k+1$. Please see [Prime Number Races.](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf) Counterexamples are actually not rare, but the first one is big.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem is proven true...

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then $2^p-1$ is not divisible by $p^2$. See Wieferich primes.

Comment: This rings a bell...duplicate?

Comment: There are some nice examples [in this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-apparent-patterns-that-eventually-fail).

Comment: All prime numbers are odd :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 And every positive integer divisible only by 1 and itself is prime!

Comment: $\prod_{i=0}^n(x-i)$ is zero for $x=0, ... n$ but not thereafter.

Comment: The best example that I know is the Gauss conjecture about two curves, that Liouville proved he was wrong. The number that proves Gauss was wrong is estimated to be ridiculously long. Some day I wrote an answer =)

Comment: One of the important surprises in number theory that I like, Gauss' updated approximation for the number of primes below $x$,
$$
\pi(n) \sim \operatorname{Li}(n) =  \int_2^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\ln x}.
$$

For all values of $n$ that we can check, $\pi(n) < \operatorname{Li}(n)$. "As a result, many prominent mathematicians, including no less than both Gauss and Riemann, conjectured that the inequality was strict."

Comment: However, Littlewood (1914) proved that the inequality reverses infinitely often for sufficiently large  $n$, and Skewes then showed that the first crossing point must occur before $$n= 10^{10^{10^{34}}}$$
which is now known as Skewes number. This bound has since been lowered to $10^{371}$.

Answer (score 50):

The following [spikedmath](http://spikedmath.com/294.html) is cute.

[image: SM]

The books "Counterexamples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach as well as "Counterexamples in Analysis" by Gelbaum  and Olmstead have some that are surprising when you first see them.

Answer (score 24):

For every $n$
$$\int_0^\infty 2 \cos(x) \prod_{i=0}^n\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2i+1}}{\frac{x}{2i+1}}\,dx=\pi/2$$

Is it true? Well, for every $n$ less than 56, but after...

An example of Borwein integral.

Comment: I.e. provided $\prod_{i=0}^n \dfrac1{2i+1}<3$.

Answer (score 11):

Pierre de Fermat conjectured that all Fermat numbers  were prime, and a similar
mistaken conjecture can be made for most pseudoprimes (Catalan, Fibonacci, Euler, Wieferich, etc.).
Also see Euler's sum of Powers conjecture , and the Polya conjecture.

Comment: Oh, and Merten's conjecture.

Answer (score 7):

Fermat's ‘little’ theorem states that if $n$ is prime, then  $$a^n\equiv a\pmod n\tag{$\ast$}$$ holds for all $a$.  The converse, which is false, states that if $(\ast)$ holds for all $a$, then $n$ is prime.

[Counterexamples to this converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) are uncommon; the smallest is $n=561$.

Answer (score 6):

The largest odd value of $n$ such that regular $n$-gons are constructable by compass and straight edge is $n=1~431~655~765$.

There is one known exception: $n=4~294~967~295$.

All in all, there are currently only $31$ known constructable regular polygons with an odd number of sides. Prior to Gauss, the largest odd-sided constructable regular polygon was just the pentagon. No doubt much of the numerological and mystical lore surrounding the pentagon and pentagram can be traced back to observations by the ancients that this five sided shape represented some fundamental boundary between the world of finite imperfect man on one side, and the perfect and infinite on the other.

Comment: I'd expect the ancients were smart enough to construct the regular $15$-gon from the triangle and pentagon.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right. Book IV, Proposition 16, of *Elements* in fact gives the construction. Now editing.

Comment: Is there something missing in the first paragraphs, like "for all $n\leq N$"? The first sentence seems to say that the largest odd $n$ for which $P_n$ is true is $n=1\,431\,655\,765$. What is the exception? That $P_m$ is true for $m=4\,294\,967\,295$? If so, then what is the point of the first sentence?

Comment: @JiK Exactly. If the first number was $15$ or something it would make more sense, but the fact that the first number itself is so large makes the point of the first example pointless. All it's saying is that the largest known example of a constructable regular polygon with odd sides is $n = 4294967295$, and the second largest example is $n = 1431655765$..

Answer (score 6):

[Euler's Sum of Powers Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture):

$$a_1^k+\ldots+a_n^k=b^k\qquad\text{with }k>n>1$$

has no solutions in positive integers.

The smallest counterexample is

$$95800^4 + 217519^4 + 414560^4 = 422481^4$$

Comment: smallest in what sense?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Smallest in lexicographic order $(k,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$.

Answer (score 4):

If  $\ n\ $ that $\ ◎(n)=\frac{n+1}{2^x}$ or $\ ◎(n)=\frac{n-1}{2^x}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z^+},\ x \in \mathbb{N}_{\gt 0},\ $then $\ n\ $ is prime.
First  counter-example is $\ 92673$.
$◎(n)\ $ is called the *cycle length of $n$* , detail see: [How to prove these two ways give the same numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394408/how-to-prove-these-two-ways-give-the-same-numbers)

Comment: If change 'then  $\ n\ $  is prime' to 'then  $\ n\ $  is prime or semiprime' ,then $\ 92673\ $ is the only known counter-example.

Answer (score 4):

[Lucke numbers of Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_numbers_of_Euler):

For every natural number $n$, the following number is prime:
$$n^2-n+41$$

The smallest $n$ for which this conjecture is wrong, is 41 -- naturally.