# Handwaving gone wrong

Tags: proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, big-list

My motivation for this question is twofold: On one hand, I'm studying algebraic topology, where - at least in the book written by Hatcher - there is quite a lot of handwaving (e.g. maps are continous because it's obvious from the picture). On the other, I'm going to be a TA next term, where it might come in handy to have some examples of handwaving gone wrong.

I'd like to see two types of examples:

1) Tell me about typical handwaving-related mistakes which math undergraduates are prone to.

2) Are there examples of handwaving in more advanced math that was possibly published and only the peer-review process uncovered it? The longer it took for somebody to notice, the cooler I'd consider the example.

Comment: Related: ['Obvious' theorems that are actually false](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/820686/25554). In particular, I mentioned there that [Frege's reliance on a principle of unrestricted comprehension](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/820785/25554) is famous, because it wasn't until shortly before the publication of the *second* volume of *Grundgesetze der Arithmetik* that Russell pointed out that this intuitively appealing and crucial principle was actually false.

Comment: Also possibly useful: [Examples of apparent patterns that eventually fail](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111440/examples-of-apparent-patterns-that-eventually-fail).  Related: [Statements with rare counter-examples](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809912/statements-with-rare-counter-examples)

Answer (score 4):

[Check this out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics)

That link is to a math overflow thread that has roughly 200 responses and covers a range of topics. It lists some commonly believed - but ultimately false - ideas in mathematics.

For example, one of the things it discusses is a commonly-held belief in American schools (primary and secondary) that Pi is 22/7, and is therefore a rational number.

I imagine that one thread will provide hours of reading and consideration!  Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a very nice list/thread.