# Is there a Poulet number with this condition?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a Poulet number $n$ with this condition: $◎(n)=\frac{n+1}{2^x}$ or $\ ◎(n)=\frac{n-1}{2^x}, \ x \in \mathbb{N}_{\gt 0}$? (Recall that a [Poulet number](http://www.numbersaplenty.com/both_Poulet_and_Proth.html) is a composite $n$ such that $2^n−2$ is divisible by $n$.)

Here $◎(n)$ is called the *cycle length of $n$*. For an example satisfying this condition: $◎(29)=14=\frac{29-1}{2^1}$.

For detail of the *cycle length of $n$* see: [How to prove these two ways give the same numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394408/how-to-prove-these-two-ways-give-the-same-numbers).

Known Composite numbers  satisfying this condition are:

> 92673, 143713, 3579553, 4110529, 28688897, 127017857, 141127681, 157648097, 162101441, 212999489, 393300097, 663414881

See http://oeis.org/A225890 (all aren't Poulet number)

If non-existence of such numbers proved imply this fact: n must be prime such that $\ \frac{n-1}{ord_n 2}=2^x\ $ and $◎(n)=\frac{n \pm 1}{2^y},\ n \in   \mathbb{Z^+} ,\ x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0},\ \ y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\gt 0}$.

The form $\ \frac{n-1}{ord_n 2}=2^x\ $ see:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168045/are-all-counterexamples-of-oeis-a226181-both-poulet-numbers-and-proth-numbers.